# Javascript to make changes to elements located inside an iframe in HighLevel

Tags: javascript

I'll preface this by saying that I don't know Javascript at all.  But anyway, there are elements inside of HighLevel (a marketing and crm software) that are iframed and hosted on another domain.  I am trying to make some basic changes to some elements, such as the button background color.  I cannot edit the code of individual pages in HighLevel, but there is an area in the settings to add custom CSS and JS.  I've used these areas to edit tons of elements in HighLevel that are not in iframes.  Can this be done?

Like I said, I don't know Javascript.  So I watched a tutorial of a guy who was able to make advanced edits in HighLevel by having ChatGPT generate the code.  However, he didn't try to change anything inside of an iframe.  But I gave ChatGPT a try and uploaded the code it generated.  No change.

Comment: So you want to change content from other origin in an iframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit cross-domain Iframe content Locally Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525274/edit-cross-domain-iframe-content-locally-only)

Comment: Yes.  I used a app called The Marketer's Toolkit that loads a script into HighLevel to make visual edits.  It changed some of the buttons in the iframes but not all of them.  Trying to see if the rest can be changed.